# How to add an element to the top of the list Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to add an element to the top of a list having stringified object in neo4j using cypher, i can add the element at the end using the below query:

```
MATCH (N) set N.existingArray=N.existingArray+'{"a":"5","b":"10"}';
```

To add at the begining i tried using reverse function present in neo4j https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reverse-list to first reverse the array :

```
MATCH (N) SET N.existingArray=reverse(N.existingArray)+'{"a":"5","b":"10"}';
```

But this gives me error :

```
Neo4jError: Expected a string or a list; consider converting it to a string with toString()
```

Can someone help me in finding a solution for this problem ?

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to append at the beginning rather than the end:

```
MATCH (N) 
SET N.existingArray = '{"a":"5","b":"10"}' + N.existingArray;
```